# Compare illumina sequencing output with reference genome

Tags: genomics, wgs, bacteria

I am new to whole genome sequencing. I want to compare illumina whole genome sequencing of mutants of a particular bacteria with a genome (not annotated) of the original strain to look for what the mutations are, how would I do about doing that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.